# libupnp static library on linux

Tags: linux, virtualbox, upnp

(Linux Debian on VirtualBox)

I want use libupnp with static library in a project.

The compilation is all good with :

```
./configure 
make
```

I find my "**.so**" "**.a**" in ./upnp/.libs and i use "**libupnp.a**" on my future Makefile in my project.

But when i use my projet who calls this static library, it doesn't work.

I tried with shared library with
cp ../upnp/.libs/libupnp.so /usr/local/lib
and call it in my Makefile, my project work good with no problems

Others library static with "**.a**" works good too but no with "**libupnp.a**"

What is/are the solution(s) to use libupnp on linux with static library?
What are the configuration?

Thanks

Regards
Remi

Comment: what dose not work? which errors do you get?

Comment: You have problem with linking using static library (even if shared library works okay)?

Answer (score 0):

My project creates a library ".so", the compilation is ok.

And to create this i use a Makefile who uses fiew libraries, and i want use static library and no shared library.

I know the problem comes to libupnp.

Because when i try with libupnp in shared library, all is ok, 
but when i use libupnp with static library, my project doesn't work and don't want read final ".so".

So my question was about compilation of libupnp to create static library.

Because i use other static library on this project and i haven't problem, i have only a problem with libupnp in static ".a"

(i use last libupnp of pupnp)